# Why isn't my CakePHP find function returning any results?

Tags: cakephp

I'm fairly new to cakePHP and ran into a problem that I can't seem to get my head around.

While trying to find some info from two tables I get this:

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "Match"

I have two models, `Club` and `Match`.
The clubs table doesn't have anything related to matches.
The matches table has an `hometeamid` and an `awayteamid` which relates to clubs(id).

Since a match is played by two clubs and can be played both at home or away I've had to do the connections a bit differently than normal. As for the connections on the models:

```
Club $hasMany = array('HomeMatch' => array('className' => 'Match','foreignKey' => 'hometeamid'), 'AwayMatch' => array('className' => 'Match','foreignKey' => 'awayteamid'));

Match $belongsTo = array('HomeTeam' => array('className' => 'Club', 'foreignKey' => 'hometeamid'), 'AwayTeam' => array('className' => 'Club', 'foreignKey' => 'awayteamid'));
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1046/Multiple-relations-to-the-same-model

While trying to find all home matches, I do this:

```
$this->Club->HomeMatch->find('all',array('fields' => array('Match.id', 'Match.status', 'Match.matchdate', 'Match.stadium_id')));
```

Unfortunately, this gives the error I mentioned at the top.

I'm not quite sure what the problem is. I can see that it says it's missing a FROM clause for table "Match" but, I can't really make sense of that.

***Updated info from comments:***

Here is the debug SQL:

```
SELECT "Match"."id" AS "Match__id", "Match"."status" AS "Match__status", "Match"."matchdate" AS "Match__matchdate", "Match"."stadium_id" AS "Match__stadium_id" 
FROM "matches" AS "HomeMatch" 
  LEFT JOIN "clubs" AS "HomeTeam" ON ("HomeMatch"."hometeamid" = "HomeTeam"."id") 
  LEFT JOIN "clubs" AS "AwayTeam" ON ("HomeMatch"."awayteamid" = "AwayTeam"."id") 
WHERE 1 = 1
```

A bit more work and I've narrowed it down to my find. I can see that the model connections work perfectly, but my find is not working as it should.

```
$this->set('homematches', $this->Club->HomeMatch->find('all', array( 'fields' => array('HomeMatch.id', 'HomeMatch.status', 'HomeMatch.matchdate', 'HomeMatch.stadium_id'))));
```

This find doesn't produce any errors, but it doesn't give any result either. When I try to retrieve something from `homematches` in the view, cake tells me:

> Undefined variable: homematches

What now?

Comment: Could you post the SQL log output for the query too?

Comment: Yes of course:  SELECT "Match"."id" AS "Match__id", "Match"."status" AS "Match__status", "Match"."matchdate" AS "Match__matchdate", "Match"."stadium_id" AS "Match__stadium_id" FROM "matches" AS "HomeMatch" LEFT JOIN "clubs" AS "HomeTeam" ON ("HomeMatch"."hometeamid" = "HomeTeam"."id") LEFT JOIN "clubs" AS "AwayTeam" ON ("HomeMatch"."awayteamid" = "AwayTeam"."id")  WHERE 1 = 1"

Comment: Apparently it has something to do with the "Match" in SELECT "Match".something...It should be SELECT "HomeMatch".something, I believe. But I have no idea how to make the changes in cake.

Comment: A bit more work and I've narrowed it down to my find. I can see that the model connections work perfectly, but my find is not working as it should.
$this->set('homematches', $this->Club->HomeMatch->find('all', array(
'fields' => array('HomeMatch.id', HomeMatch.status', 'HomeMatch.matchdate', 'HomeMatch.stadium_id'))));
This find doesn't produce any errors, but it doesn't give any result either. When I try to retrieve something from homematches in the view, cake tells me: Undefined variable: homematches

Comment: `HomeMatch.id` ect is the correct syntax; have you verified that your select statement is returning results in SQL?

Comment: It all works now. My blindness is mind boggling :)
I had my find in the wrong function in clubs_controller. This is why I couldn't retrieve homematches in the view.
I'm sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: It's fine; go ahead and explain your solution in an answer and accept it =). We encourage self-learning too!

Answer (score 0):

The error you get doesn't mean that there something wrong with the query.

You need to make sure that this line:

```
$this->set('homematches', $this->Club->HomeMatch->find('all', array( 'fields' => array('HomeMatch.id', HomeMatch.status', 'HomeMatch.matchdate', 'HomeMatch.stadium_id'))));
```

is in the controller file and there's a render function after it.

There's a disconnection between the "set" function to the view file.
Add the whole function code (where the above line is located) please.